# Android: Distinguishing between scaling and other multi-touch gestures

Tags: android, multi-touch, gesture

I'm currently in the process of creating an application in which a large amount of input is through the use of surface gestures. This also involves the use of multi-touch gestures. In a very short amount of time I have come to discover that handling multi-touch gestures in Android is a pain.

One of the multi-touch gestures in my system is a simple drag gesture whereby the user drags two fingers down the screen while keeping them roughly parallel to each other (think of a "pause" symbol). I'm also making use of the pinch gesture using the `SimpleOnScaleGestureListener` class.

Long story short, this is not working well. My system just cannot distinguish between the scale and the "pause" drag. In particular, it is recognising the scale and ignoring the "pause" gesture.

This is driving me crazy. Is there any way around this?